# Из пары xml csv нужно сделать json

Tags: c#, json, xml, csv

XML:

```
<Category everyone>
    <Name>VH</Name>
    <Children>
        <Category everyone>
            <Name>Moto</Name>
        </Category>
        <Category>
            <Name>BMW</Name>
            <Children>
                <Category everyone>
                    <Name>Sedan</Name>
                </Category>
                <Category>
                    <Name>Coupe</Name>
                </Category>
            </Children>
    </Children>
</Category>
```

CSV:

```
VH.BMW.Sedan;"BMW 320i"
VH.BMW.Coupe;"BMW 330"
VH.Moto;"Yamaha Aim Pro 29"
VH.BMW.Coupe;"BMW 520"
```

Нужно сделать Json:

```
[
    {
        "category":"Sedan",
        "forAll": true,
        "parentCategory":"VH.BMW",
        "values":[
            "BMW 320i"
        ]
    },
    {
        "category":"Coupe",
        "forAll": false,
        "parentCategory":"VH.BMW",
        "values":[
            "BMW 330",
            "BMW 520"
        ]
    },
        {
        "category":"Moto",
        "forAll": true,
        "parentCategory":"VH",
        "values":[
            "Yamaha Aim Pro 29"
        ]
    }
]
```

Я понимаю как парсить XML в strcontainer и как парсить csv с помощью dictionary, но что значит пара xml csv, я не понимаю. Класс Xdocument для C# имеет большой функционал.

Comment: Я понимаю как парсить XML в strcontainer и как парсить csv с помощью dictionary, но что значит пара xml csv, я не понимаю. Класс Xdocument для C# имеет большой функционал.

Comment: Имеется в виду, что на вход вам приходят в каком-то виде два файла, а вы должны их распарсить и сделать из них третий.

Comment: Кстати, ваш XML не валиден, атрибут everyone должен иметь значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня после исправления XML (`<Category everyone="true">`) работает вот так:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Category));
Category rootCategory;
using (var s = File.OpenText(@"x.xml"))
    rootCategory = (Category)ser.Deserialize(s);

Dictionary<string, Entry> entries = new();
FillDictionary(rootCategory, null);

void FillDictionary(Category category, string parentName)
{
    var entry = new Entry()
    {
        ParentCategory = parentName,
        Category = category.Name,
        ForAll = category.Everyone
    };
    var fullName = parentName == null ? category.Name : $"{parentName}.{category.Name}";
    entries[fullName] = entry;
    if (category.Children != null)
        foreach (var childCategory in category.Children)
            FillDictionary(childCategory, fullName);
}

using (var csv = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(@"x.csv"))
{
    csv.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
    csv.SetDelimiters(";");
    while (!csv.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] fields = csv.ReadFields();
        var categoryName = fields[0];
        var modelName = fields[1];

        if (!entries.TryGetValue(categoryName, out var entry))
            throw new Exception($"Unexpected category: {categoryName}");

        entry.Values ??= new();
        entry.Values.Add(modelName);
    }
}

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    entries.Values.Where(v => v.Values != null),
    new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true,
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    });
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Вспомогательные классы:

```
class Entry
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool ForAll { get; set; }
    public string ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("Category", IsNullable = false)]
    public Category[] Children { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("everyone")]
    public bool Everyone { get; set; }
}
```

Вместо консоли можно записать результат и в файл:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(@"x.json"))
using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream, new JsonWriterOptions { Indented = true }))
JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    writer,
    entries.Values.Where(v => v.Values != null),
    new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @MaoriAngel: Да куда оно денется :)